# getting the first two bytes of a http.get Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https, aws-lambda

I need the first two bytes of a http.get (for magic varification), in a AWS lambda function.
this is my code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var https = require('https');
var url= "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=806f533220&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-a:r-8750932957918989452&th=168b03149469bc1f&view=att&disp=safe&realattid=f_jro0gbqh0";


var result= https.get(url , (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
    });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
       console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });

    callback(null, '3');// I want to return the first two bytes...
};
```

any ideas?
thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the `callback` too soon, i.e. before you received the callback from the `resp`. Try moving the callback, e.g.

```
resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
  data += chunk;
  var data = // here you may have the data you need, either call the callback temporarily or execute the callback immediately
  callback(null, data);
});
```

or wait for the `resp` to end:

```
resp.on('end', () => {
  // pass the temporarily stored data to the callback
  callback(null, data);
});
```

or if the `resp` result in an error:

```
resp.on("error", (err) => {
   console.log("Error: " + err.message);
   callback(err);  // make sure to let the caller of Lambda know that the request failed
});
```